# From convergence of sequences to uniform convergence in probability

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

For $n=1, 2,\ldots$ consider a sequence of sets of ascending integers $I_n=\{\underline{i}_n,\underline{i}_n+1, \ldots,  \overline{i}_n\}$, with $\underline{i}_n   \to \infty$ and $\underline{i}_n=o(\overline{i}_n)$ as $n \to \infty$. Consider a corresponding array of random variables (defined on the same probability space) $\{X_{n,i}, i \in I_n\}$, $n=1,2, \ldots$

Then define the class $\mathcal{I}$ of integer sequences $(i_n)$ such that $i_n \in I_n$ for $n =1, 2, \ldots$ and assume that for any $(i_n) \in \mathcal{I}$ the sequence of random variables $(X_{n,i_n})$ converges in probability to a constant $c$, in symbols $X_{n,i_n} \overset{p}{\to}c$, i.e.
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X_{n,i_n}-c|> \epsilon) \to 0
$$
as $n \to \infty$, for any arbitrarily small $\epsilon>0$.

**QUESTION** Can we claim that $\max_{i \in I_n}|X_{n,i}-c|$ converges to zero in probability?

**My attempt** I have the impression that, by a diagonal argument, the answer is yes. Consider first the sequence $(\underline{i}_n)$, then by assumption $X_{n,\underline{i}_n} \overset{p}{\to}c$ and (e.g., Billingsley, 1995, Th. 20.5(ii)) for any subsequence $(n')$ one can extract a further subsequence $(n'_1)$ such that $$
|X_{n'_1, \underline{i}_{n_1'}}-c|\overset{a.s.}{\to} , 
$$
where $\overset{a.s.}{\to}$ denotes almost sure convergence. Then, since also $X_{n,\underline{i}_n+1} \overset{p}{\to}c$, there is a further subsequence $(n'_2)$ such that
$$
\max\{|X_{n'_2, \underline{i}_{n'_2}}-c|, |X_{n'_2, \underline{i}_{n'_2}+1}-c| \} \overset{a.s.}{\to}0
$$
and iterating this reasoning it should be possible to finally claim that there is a subsequence $(n'')$ of $(n')$ over which
$$
\max_{i \in I_{n''}}|X_{n'', i}-c| \overset{a.s.}{\to}0.
$$
In this way, we would have then established that for any subsequence $(\max_{i \in I_{n'}} |X_{n',i}-c |)$ of $(\max_{i \in I_{n}} |X_{n,i}-c |)$ there is a further subsequence which converges to zero almost surely, which (again by Th. 20.5(ii) in Billingsley, 1995) is equivalent to convergence in probability of $(\max_{i \in I_{n}} |X_{n,i}-c |)$ to zero. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no in general.

Indeed, suppose that $I_n=\{2^n+1,\dots,(n+1)2^n\}$, $X_{n,i}=Y_i$, $P(Y_i=1)=1/i=1-P(Y_i=0)$, the $Y_i$'s are independent, and $c=0$. Then all your conditions hold.

However, for
\begin{equation}
    Z_n:=\max_{i\in I_n}|X_{n,i}-c|=\max_{i\in I_n}Y_i
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
    P(Z_n=1)=1-\prod_{i\in I_n}(1-1/i) \\ 
    \ge1-\exp\Big(-\sum_{i\in I_n}1/i\Big)
    \ge1-\exp\Big(-\sum_{i=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}}1/i\Big) \\ 
    \ge1-\exp\Big(-2^n/2^{n+1}\Big)
    =1-e^{-1/2},
\end{equation}
so that $Z_n\not\to0$ in probability.